# Can I convert PDF blob to image using Python and Wand?

Tags: python, wand

I'm trying to convert a PDF's first page to an image. However, the PDF is coming straight from the database in a base64 format. I then convert it to a blob. I want to know if it's possible to convert the first page of the PDF to an image within my Python code.

I'm familiar with being able to use filename in the Image object:

```
Image(filename="test.pdf[0]") as img:
```

The issue I'm facing is there is not an actual filename, just a blob. This is what I have so far, any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
x = object['file']
fileBlob = base64.b64decode('x')
with Image(**what do I put here for pdf blob?**) as img:
    more code
```

Comment: HOPE THIS HELPS - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129995/pdf-to-raw-image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129995/pdf-to-raw-image)

Answer (score 2):

It works for me

```
all_pages = Image(blob=blob_pdf)        # PDF will have several pages.
single_image = all_pages.sequence[0]    # Just work on first page
with Image(single_image) as i:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.1/wand/image.html#wand.image.Image) says something about blobs.
So it should be:

```
with Image(blob=fileBlob):
    #etc etc
```

I didn't test that but I think this is what you are after.

Comment: I've tried that previously and get the message "wand.exceptions.WandError: wand contains no images `MagickWand-1' @ error/magick-image.c/MagickWriteImage/13115"

Comment: Are you sure then that this is the correct way to get your fileBlob?
try this, it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26233785/2876209
Also I notice in your code you are giving 'x'(a string) instead of x(which is the object) as an argument to the decode function. That could be the error if this is the way you do it in your code too.